# Can we create multiple sheets using Google Sheet API the way we create manually?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I want to add multiple sheets with different values under a google sheet but I cannot find it anywhere. Is it possible?

Comment: Please see [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear.  In case you're looking for a python way of adding new sheets, then you can refer to google sheets API documentation to Add sheets.  You may use the [Batch Update and Add Sheet request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet?hl=en)

```
    {
  "requests": [
    {
      "addSheet": {
        "properties": {
          "title": <<Your Sheet Name Goes Here>>,
          "gridProperties": {
            "rowCount": 20,
            "columnCount": 12
          },
          "tabColor": {
            "red": 1.0,
            "green": 0.3,
            "blue": 0.4
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```